# How to increase performance in multiple Json.Convert deserialization inside a loop?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have created a loop, and inside this loop, I am using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject multiple times.
I wonder if there is any way to improve performance.

```
foreach (var mainItem in jsonItems)
{
   var jsonItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MainGridViewClass>>(mainItem.JsonString);
   foreach (var item in jsonItems)
   {
      // actions
   }
}
```

Comment: if it's the same data, the most obvious way to put the deserialisation _outside_ of the loop and only do it once.

Comment: No its not the same data, i have changed my question.

Comment: Parallel processing? How many items are in jsonItems?

Comment: Before taking steps for "improving performance" you should evaluate if the performance of that particular piece of code is even a problem ...

Comment: What about DefaultContractResolver?

Comment: You need to run a profiler and see where time is being taken.  No way to answer without more information, ideally a [mcve] showing where the problem is.  See: [ask].